# Document Design and Document IDs

Tags: database-design, nosql, couchdb, document-oriented

I was wondering about specifying id's in CouchDB. For example:

House
- Rooms
-- Kitchen
-- Living room
-- ...
- Windows
- Doors

There are some documents, like "House", where there is and will only be one document of this type. Should I specify the id "house" for this document for quick access or rather use a generated id?

Answer (score 1):

It's best not to use the name of a "type" as an id - it is better to use generated id's and have a key called "type"  in each document where you have a string value of "Home" etc